# Getting column name and index name in front of the values-Panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
                 Jan  Feb  Mar   
Supplier01       100  100  100  
Supplier02       200  200  200 
Supplier03      5000   49  359  
Supplier04       500  500  500
```

I have managed to get the above dataframe using the below code

```
monthset=["Jan","Feb","Mar"]
supplierset=["Supplier01","Supplier02","Supplier03","Supplier04"]
```

data is a list of list as below

```
data=[[100,100,100],[200,200,200],[5000,49,359],[500,500,500]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=monthset,index=supplierset)
```

How can I get an output as bellow

```
Supplier01,Jan,100
Supplier01,Feb,100
```

etc..
Basically infront of an elemnt value the column name and index name with comma seperated.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but seems you need `melt`.

Comment: `df.reset_index().melt('index')` or `df.reset_index().melt('index').sort_values('index').reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df['supplier'] = df.index
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['supplier'], var_name=['Month'], value_name='Value')
```

Output:

```
      supplier Month  Value
0   Supplier01   Jan    100
1   Supplier02   Jan    200
2   Supplier03   Jan   5000
3   Supplier04   Jan    500
4   Supplier01   Feb    100
5   Supplier02   Feb    200
6   Supplier03   Feb     49
7   Supplier04   Feb    500
8   Supplier01   Mar    100
9   Supplier02   Mar    200
10  Supplier03   Mar    359
11  Supplier04   Mar    500
```

Comment: Iam getting an error as 'supplier' is not defined.Looks like and 'supplier is an object and based on that melting is not happening..